# XSLT add attributes to elements in a variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

In XSLT 1.0 I have a variable with some XML nodes:

```
<xsl:varible name="MyVariable">
   <SomeElement>text here</SomeElement>
   <SomeElement>text with <OtherElement>other element</OtherElement></SomeElement>
   <SomeElement>something else <DoNotAddAnything>...</DoNotAddAnything></SomeElement>
</xsl:variable>
```

I need to add an attribute with some value to elements SomeElement and OtherElement (but not to others). I need to transform the content of the variable to something like this:

```
   <SomeElement NewAttribute="x">text here</SomeElement>
   <SomeElement NewAttribute="x">text with <OtherElement OtherAttribute="y">other element</OtherElement></SomeElement>
   <SomeElement NewAttribute="x">something else <DoNotAddAnything>...</DoNotAddAnything></SomeElement>
```

This is part of larger transformation, and I only need to do this for the content of the variable, not for the entire input of XSLT transformation. I found easy solutions for converting entire input (xsl:apply-template) but I'm having hard times to achieve the same only for the content of a variable.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you transform the content of a variable instead of transforming a document? Why not just store content exactly the way you need it in _another_ variable?

Comment: You need to convert the variable to a node-set, using the EXSLT exsl:node-set() extension function.Then you can apply templates (or `<xsl:for each>`) to it - just as if it were a source XML document.

Comment: Matias Müller: May be you are right and I chose wrong approach. I'll try to describe the situation. I have lots of input XML files with a few elements containing some information. For each type of these input XML files (there are tens of different types of input information) I'm creating HTML (some short paraghaphs with links and other HTML tags, like strong, em etc.). So each type has its own XSLT template. Generated HTML I need to put in much larger general template for mailing (really lots of code, wrote by other company). To each paragraph and anchor I need to add style attribute.

Answer (score 1):

> In XSLT 1.0 I have a variable with some XML nodes:

That's a misconception. You have a variable with a *result tree fragment*, which is strictly not the same as *"some XML nodes"*.

You must convert the result tree fragment back to actual XML nodes. With vanilla XSLT 1.0 this is not possible, but many XSLT processors have an extension function called `node-set()` that does just that. How to enable that function depends on your specific XSLT processor.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($MyVariable)" />
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="SomeElement">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:attribute name="NewAttribute">x</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
  <xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

That said, it strikes me as odd that you're trying to use a variable with "some XML nodes" in it. Except for very special cases you should not have to do that, so I think you might be doing something wrong.

---

Note that

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" select="/some/xml/nodes" />
```

does *not* contain a result tree fragment, but an ordinary node set.

However, a variable that is not defined via `select="..."` *never* contains actual nodes, but always result tree fragments (which you can think about as strings, basically).

Comment: Re your final sentence, in XSLT 1.0 a variable defined with content instead of a `select` is _always_ a result tree fragment.  It may be a fragment consisting of a single text node, but it's still a fragment, not a string or a number.  This does matter in some cases, e.g. `foo[$count]` behaves differently for `<xsl:variable name="count" select="2"/>` (number) vs. `<xsl:variable name="count">2</xsl:variable>` (RTF).

Comment: I suppose there's one exception - `<xsl:variable name="emptyString" />` is an empty string rather than an empty fragment.

Comment: @IanRoberts I tend to think about result tree fragments as (a subclass of) strings anyway. Is there a distinction beyond that?

Comment: You can send a complete fragment to the output tree using `<xsl:copy-of select="$myRtfVariable"/>`.  The difference between an RTF and a node set is simply that you can't descend into an RTF using XPath expressions, you can only output it as a single unit.