# XSLT: Getting the position of an element in the new XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to add a growing, not-resetting sequence number to ALL of the elements in the XML based in their new position. I tried using this as an attribute

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::* | ancestor::*) + 1" />
```

However, this will result the sequence numbers being based on the element's original location in the document.

My original XML, created from multiple XMl files with "copy-of":

```
<title>
  <article>
    <paragraph>
      <subparagraph>
      </subparagraph>
    </paragraph>
  </article>
</title>
```

I remove the unneccessary 'article' tag from the new XML with XSLT. The result is then this:

```
<title id="1">
  <paragraph id="3">
    <subparagraph id="4">
    </subparagraph>
  </paragraph>
</title>
```

The result I desire:

```
<title id="1">
  <paragraph id="2">
    <subparagraph id="3">
    </subparagraph>
  </paragraph>
</title>
```

What is the optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: XSLT does not track the output tree. If you cannot produce the required numbers from the input (e.g. by **not** counting the `article` nodes), then make another pass.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks, I was afraid this would be the case.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can do both passes in the same stylesheet, if you so prefer - by outputting the first pass into a variable.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Hi Michael, according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348434/xslt-add-attributes-to-elements-in-a-variable) it might not be possible to do as you suggested (in basic XMLT 1.0). Any opinion on that? Or should I take a different approach than the OP in the other post?

Comment: Practically all XSLT 1.0 processors support an extension function to convert a result-tree-fragment into a node-set, if that's your concern. See, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471442/applying-xslt-template-one-after-the-other-for-removing-empty-nodes/28473525#28473525

Comment: @michael.hor257k Cool, thanks, I'll look into your example

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:number count="*[not(self::article)]" level="any"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="article">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you can count the elements you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, since there are a lot of nodes to skip it might be best to do a separate XSLT for the new XML for this purpose.